# multiple recyclerviews?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I want to make my homepage with two row  with recyclerview
with data of books and  the events which are display independent of each other how can i accomplish it I want to add event to the my code how can i do it?

MoviesAdapter.java

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Movie> moviesList;
public Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView thumbnail;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.book);

    }
}//End of MyViewHolder class

public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

//display different items in the data set
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

//display data at specified location
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(moviesList.get(position).getTitle());

    holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(moviesList.get(position).getImage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
}
```

I want to make my page like this

[image]

Comment: Will the screen only show a few independent lists (like in your sketch) or will there be a lot?

Comment: there be a lot so we can swipe to right and see more books and  different events

Comment: I meant will there be more categories? Or just "Authors", " Books" and "Events" ( and maybe 2-3 more)

Comment: no just three authors books and events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine to use a LinearLayout with 3 RecyclerViews in it and create an Adapter for each of them. Nested RecyclerViews would only make sense if you had a lot of categories.

Comment: do you know how to do search on list with multiple recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

I done it with the three recyclerview and their adapter class here is the code of only MainActivity.java and activity.xml

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Author> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView3;

    private BookAdapter bAdapter;
    private AuthorAdapter aAdapter;
    private EventAdapter eAdapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView1 =  findViewById(R.id.recycler_book);
        bAdapter = new BookAdapter(this,bookList);
        recyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true);
         RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(bAdapter);
        prepareBookData();

      //second recycler
        recyclerView2 =  findViewById(R.id.recycler_author);
        aAdapter = new AuthorAdapter(this,authorList);
        recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager aLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(aLayoutManager);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(aAdapter);
        prepareAuthorData();

        //third recycler
        recyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_event);
        eAdapter = new EventAdapter(this,eventList);
        recyclerView3.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //   RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
        recyclerView3.setAdapter(eAdapter);
        prepareEventData();
    }

    private void prepareBookData(){

        int[] drawableArray = {R.drawable.youcanwin, R.drawable.halfgirl};
        String[] nameArray = {"You Can Win", "Half Girlfriend"};
        Book a=new Book(nameArray[0],drawableArray[0]);
        bookList.add(a);

        Book b=new Book(nameArray[1],drawableArray[1]);
        bookList.add(b);

        Book c=new Book(nameArray[0],drawableArray[0]);
        bookList.add(c);

        bAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void prepareAuthorData(){

        int[] drawableArray = {R.drawable.youcanwin, R.drawable.halfgirl};
        String[] nameArray = {"You Can Win", "Half Girlfriend"};

        Author a=new Author(nameArray[0],drawableArray[0]);
        authorList.add(a);

        Author b=new Author(nameArray[1],drawableArray[1]);
        authorList.add(b);

        Author c=new Author(nameArray[0],drawableArray[0]);
        authorList.add(c);

        Author d=new Author(nameArray[1],drawableArray[1]);
        authorList.add(d);

        bAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void prepareEventData(){

        String[] desArray = {"new","old"};
        String[] nameArray = {"You Can Win", "Half Girlfriend"};

        Event a=new Event(nameArray[0],desArray[0]);
        eventList.add(a);

        Event b=new Event(nameArray[0],desArray[0]);
        eventList.add(b);

        Event c=new Event(nameArray[0],desArray[0]);
        eventList.add(c);

        bAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.hardik.threerecycler.MainActivity"
android:background="#e6edec">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Books"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Authors"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_book"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Events"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_event"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_author"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you know how to do search on list with multiple recyclerview?